# Number theory and combinatorial problem

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Consider seven distinct positive integers not exceeding $1706$. Prove that there are three of them, say $a,b,c$ such that $a < b+c < 4a$.

Comment: You seemed to have missed some of the question

Comment: No. It seems to be an error in the formatting.

Comment: I am tring to edit but the edited ones do not show. I font know why

Comment: I am tring to edit but the edited ones do not show. I font know why

Comment: I fixed it for you; no need to delete.

Comment: If $a=2$, $b=3$, $c=4$, then $2<3+4<8$.

Comment: I think you didn't read the question correctly.

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between the seven. My $a$, $b$, $c$ obey the inequality and don't exceed $1706$.

Comment: Prove that for every seven distinct integers $1 \leq a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_7 \leq 1706$, there exists three $a_i, a_j, a_k$ such that $a_i < a_j + a_k < 4a_i$. Is that better?

Comment: OK, thanks Jeffery Opoku-Mensah. Yes it makes sense now. I was merely pointing out the question as set could be misconstrued and answered trivially the way I did.

Comment: Do observe that the bound $1706$ is tight! For $1,2,7,27,107,427,1707$ is a set of seven numbers where no desired triplets can be found. When you include $1$ into the set, the next one you can pick freely, but need to apply the rule $x\to 4x-1$ ever after.

Answer (score 6):

Assume that the numbers are $1\le a_1<a_2<\ldots<a_7$. Assume contrariwise that no triple satisfies the inequalities $a<b+c<4a$. This implies that for all $i=2,3,4,5,6,$ we must have $$a_{i+1}\ge4a_i-a_1,\qquad(*)$$
for otherwise $a=a_i, b=a_{i+1},c=a_1$ is a solution. Applying $(*)$ five times gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
a_3&\ge4a_2-a_1,\\
a_4&\ge16a_2-5a_1,\\
\cdots&\ge\cdots,\\
a_7&\ge1024a_2-341a_1.
\end{aligned}
$$
Because $a_2\ge a_1+1, a_1\ge1,$ this tells us that $$a_7\ge (1024-341)a_1+1024\ge683a_1+1024\ge1707.$$ A contradiction.

Comment: Is this your own solution?? Its exactly what the books soln says

Comment: Of course it is my own solution. A) I don't know what book you're reading so I couldn't read. B) It isn't that difficult a problem. It wasn't obvious to begin with, but popped out when I was trying to construct a counterexample/ a near miss (see my comment under the question). Back in my olympic days I could crack a bit more difficult ones. The tooth of time... :-)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Let the integers in increasing order be $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_7$. Realize that in base $4$, $1706_{10} = 122222_4$. Thus, divide $[1, 1706]$ into

$$\underbrace{[1, 2)}_{A_1} \cup \underbrace{[2, 10)}_{A_2} \cup \underbrace{[10, 42)}_{A_3} \cup \underbrace{[42, 170)}_{A_4} \cup \underbrace{[170, 682)}_{A_5} \cup \underbrace{[682, 1706]}_{A_6}$$

Can you use the Pigeonhole Principle now? There are two cases: one where there are at least three integers in a single $A$-set, and when there are two(then there is a sub-case here for $A_6$).